# Do I need the 3DS version to use the 3DS as a controller for the Wii U version?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

Sorry if the title made no sense.

I go a Youth group. Before it starts, we play Super smash bros on the Wii U.

I want to bring my 3DS to use as a controller, but I do not have Super smash bros on my 3DS.

The question is, do I need Super smash bros 3DS to use as a controller, to play Super smash bros Wii U?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that Nintendo recently released an application on the eShop that allows you to use your 3DS as a controller for Wii U without the game.

"If you don't have the Super Smash Bros. for Nintendo 3DS software, you can purchase and download the Smash Controller software for Nintendo 3DS beginning 6/14/15 (eShop price: $0.99)."

See: http://www.smashbros.com/us/howto/entry11.html

Comment: Lol I got the game in April but thanks

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you must have the 3DS version in order to use your 3DS as a controller for the Wii U version. That's because SSB for 3DS needs to connect to SSB for Wii U.

Edit:They have since changed this, (refer to answer above)